# Php isset && !empty dont work

Tags: php

This example works fine for me its doing what i want.
1.File

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>php test </title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['go'])&& !empty($_POST['vorname'])){


        echo " ".$_POST["vorname"];     
        echo " ".$_POST["nachname"];

                }
    else {   ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="vorname" />
        <input type="text" name="nachname" />
        <input type="submit" name="go" />

    </form>

    <?php } ?>


</body>


</html>
```

So i tried the same syntax at my test file were i try all the new php stuff that i am learning atm. but its not working at all no matter if the var "Vorname" is set or not it keeps submiting and showing the php code.But what i want is that if the var "Vorname" is empty it should show me forms again.

2nd File

```
    <div class="Mitte" style="text-align:left;" >
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Buchung'])&& !empty($_POST)) {
    ?>

    <h2> PhP Auswertung </h2>
    <?php   $Preis=0;

        $Anrede=$_POST['Anrede'];
        echo "Sehr geehreter ".$Anrede." ";


        $titel=$_POST['Titel'];
        echo "$titel";


        echo " ".$_POST['Vorname'];


        echo ' '.$_POST['Nachname'];
    ?>
    <br />
    <br />

    <?php
        echo "Ihre angegebene Adresse lautet: ";
    ?>
    <br />
    <?php

        echo 'Die Strasse : '.$_POST['Strasse'];
    ?>
    <br />

    <?php
        echo 'Die PLZ : '.$_POST['PLZ'];
    ?>
    <br />

    <?php
        echo 'Der Ort : '.$_POST['Ort'];
    ?>



    <br />
    <br />


    <?php
        echo 'Die E-mail Adresse : '.$_POST['E-mail'];
    ?>
    <br />
    <br />



    <?php
        echo "Ihre Reise Informationen: ";
    ?>
    <br/>
    <?php
        $Reise=$_POST['Reiseart'];
        echo "$Reise";
    ?>
    <br />


    <?php
        echo "Erwachsene und/oder Kinder ? <br>";
        foreach ($_POST["Reisende"] as $value ) {
        echo "$value<br>";              
                            }
    ?>

    <br />

    <?php
        echo "Gew&auml;hlte Extras:  <br>";
        foreach ($_POST['extras'] as $extra) {
        echo "$extra<br>";

        if ($extra=="Mietwagen"){
        $Preis=$Preis+200;
    }
        else if ($extra=="Versicherung"){
        $Preis=$Preis+100;
    }

        else if ($extra=="Allinkl"){
        $Preis=$Preis+750;
    }

        else if ($extra=="4Sterne upgrade"){
        $Preis=$Preis+1000;
    }



        else {  
            echo "Error Code 3000"; }
                            }//end foreach extras

    ?>

    <br />

    <?php
        echo "Ihr gew&auml;hlter Flughafen ist: ".$_POST['Flughafen'];  
    ?>

    <br />

    <?php
        $check1=$_POST['Reiseart'];
        $check2=$_POST['Flughafen'];

        if ($check1=='pauschal'){
        $Preis=$Preis+525; }

        else if ($check1=='stadt'){
        $Preis=$Preis+400;}

        else if ($check1=='wanderung'){
        $Preis=$Preis+150;}

        else {
        $Preis=$Preis+300;}


        if ($check2=='Frankfurt'){
        $Preis=$Preis+100; }

        else if ($check2=='Bonn'){
        $Preis=$Preis+50;}

        else {
        $Preis=$Preis;}

        echo "Der Preis betr&auml;gt : $Preis";
    ?>

    <?php 
        } else {            //Ende if isset start of else Html part

    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">

        <table cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td> <h1>Adresse </h1> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Anrede:</td>
                <td> <select style="margin-left:20px" name="Anrede" size="1" >
                    <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                    <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
                     </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Titel:</td>
                <td> <select style="margin-left:20px" name="Titel" size="1" >
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Dr.</option>
                    <option>Prof.</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Vorname:</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" style="background-color:#EFFBF5; margin-left:20px;" name="Vorname" /> 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Nachname:</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" style="background-color:#EFFBF5; margin-left:20px;" name="Nachname" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Strasse:</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" style="background-color:#EFFBF5; margin-left:20px;" name="Strasse" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>PLZ:</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" style="background-color:#EFFBF5; margin-left:20px;" name="PLZ"  />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Ort:</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" style="background-color:#EFFBF5; margin-left:20px;" name="Ort"  />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>E-mail:</td>
                <td> 
                <input type="text" style="background-color:#EFFBF5; margin-left:20px;" name="E-mail" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


        <p style="align:center">
            <input type="submit" name="Buchung" value="Buchen"/> 
            <input type="reset" name="Abbrechen" value="Abbrechen"/>
        </p>
    </form>

    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

I just posted the whole PHP Code and the important form part.

Comment: `A != a` there's your answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- *there's your answer*, nope it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30980271/3933332 :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Aaahhh, well will you lookah dat?! I guess it slipped my mind ;-)

Comment: This is a retundant check, please check the below this why-check-both-isset-and-empty

Comment: i change this Lines :  if (isset($_POST['Buchung'])&& isset($_POST['vorname'])){       then i change <input type="text" name="vorname"/> still same issue

Answer (score 2):

You have a letter case issue here, for many of your name attributes and POST arrays.

For example: `name="vorname"` and `$_POST['Vorname']` and the uppercase "V".

Those are case-sensitive and you need to do the same for the others also.

As I said in comments, `A != a`

FYI: `!=` translates to "does not equal".

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Changed it now for both "vorname" still same issue